# How do I import a file into r with extension .DUSMCPUB?

Tags: r, import, cdc, fixed-width

I’m trying to import the Mortality Multiple Cause Files from the National Center for Health Statistics, located at this link:

https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data_access/vitalstatsonline.htm#Downloadable

[link to image of where to find file on NCHS website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx7ZJ.png)

The files have an extension .DUSMCPUB (e.g., the file for 2020 is called "VS20MORT.DUSMCPUB_r20220105”). How do I import such a file? I’m not familiar with the extension.

I have tried to import with the following code, but it causes my R program to terminate. Can you please provide me with a suggestion on how to import these types of files?

```
VS20MORT <- read_delim("VS20MORT.DUSMCPUB_r20220105")
```

Comment: I don't see where on that linked page to find the file you are talking about.  (There are dozens of downloadable files, but the name you give isn't shown.)  Could you explain how to get the particular file you are asking about?

Comment: @user2554330 the file is located under the heading Mortality Multiple Cause Files. I'm interested in the zip file for 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Mel G for sharing this approach. When I tried to run it, I realized that the mortality file includes a few new variables as of 2020 (namely decedent’s occupation and industry). Here’s a slight variation that includes the new variables.

```
# Install and load necessary packages
# install.packages("sqldf") # Used to read in DUSMCPUB file
# install.packages("dplyr") # Used for tidy data management
library(sqldf)
library(dplyr)

#Increase memory limit to make space for large file
# memory.limit()
memory.limit(size=20000)

# Create dataframe containing variables for column width, name, and end position
columns <- data.frame(widths=c(19,1,40,2,1,1,2,2,1,4,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,16,4,1,1,1,
                               1,34,1,1,4,3,1,3,3,2,1,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
                               7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,36,2,1,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
                               5,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,2,1,1,1,1,33,3,1,1,2,315,4,2,4,2))
columns$names <- c("blank1", # tape locations 1-19
                   "Resident_Status_US",  # tape location 20
                   "blank2", 
                   "Education_1989",
                   "Education_2003",
                   "Education_flag", 
                   "Month_of_Death", 
                   "blank3",
                   "Sex", 
                   "DetailAge",
                   "Age_Substitution_Flag", 
                   "Age_Recode_52",
                   "Age_Recode_27", 
                   "Age_Recode_12",
                   "Infant_Age_Recode_22",
                   "Place_of_Death_and_Status",
                   "Marital_Status",
                   "Day_of_Week_of_Death",
                   "blank4",
                   "Current_Data_Year",
                   "Injury_at_Work",
                   "Manner_of_Death",
                   "Method_of_Disposition",
                   "Autopsy",
                   "blank5",
                   "Activity_Code",
                   "Place_of_Injury",
                   "ICD_Code_10",
                   "Cause_Recode_358",
                   "blank6",
                   "Cause_Recode_113",
                   "Infant_Cause_Recode_130",
                   "Cause_Recode_39",
                   "blank7",
                   "Number_Entity_Axis_Conditions",
                   "Condition_1EA", "Condition_2EA", "Condition_3EA", "Condition_4EA", "Condition_5EA",
                   "Condition_6EA", "Condition_7EA", "Condition_8EA", "Condition_9EA", "Condition_10EA",
                   "Condition_11EA", "Condition_12EA", "Condition_13EA", "Condition_14EA", "Condition_15EA",
                   "Condition_16EA", "Condition_17EA", "Condition_18EA", "Condition_19EA", "Condition_20EA",
                   "blank8",
                   "Number_Record_Axis_Conditions",
                   "blank9",
                   "Condition_1RA", "Condition_2RA", "Condition_3RA", "Condition_4RA", "Condition_5RA",
                   "Condition_6RA", "Condition_7RA", "Condition_8RA", "Condition_9RA", "Condition_10RA",
                   "Condition_11RA", "Condition_12RA", "Condition_13RA", "Condition_14RA", "Condition_15RA",
                   "Condition_16RA", "Condition_17RA", "Condition_18RA", "Condition_19RA", "Condition_20RA",
                   "blank10",
                   "Race",
                   "Bridged_Race_Flag",
                   "Race_Imputation_Flag",
                   "Race_Recode_3",
                   "Race_Recode_5",
                   "blank11",
                   "Hispanic_Origin",
                   "blank12",
                   "Hispanic_Origin_9_Race_Recode",
                   "Race_Recode_40",
                   "blank13",
                   "CensusOcc",
                   "Occ_26",
                   "CensusInd",
                   "Ind_23")

# Read in file using parameters from 'columns' dataframe
mort2020<- read.fwf("VS20MORT.DUSMCPUB_r20220105", widths=columns$widths, stringsAsFactors=F)
# Attach column names to variables
colnames(mort2020) <- columns$names

# Remove blank variables
mort2020x <- mort2020 %>% dplyr::select(-starts_with("blank"))
```

Alternatively, it looks like the files are published for most years in a CSV format here: https://www.nber.org/research/data/mortality-data-vital-statistics-nchs-multiple-cause-death-data. 2020 isn’t up yet, but for other years, it can be much faster to read a CSV into R than to use read.fwf.

Comment: awesome! I did not catch that there were new variables added for 2020. I changed the accepted answer to the one you posted.

Answer (score 1):

The data is in the form of a fixed-width file. The user's guide to the data from the National Center for Health Statistics contains the appropriate widths. The answer I present is a modified answer from another forum, posted by @Hack-R.

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/18375/how-can-one-interpret-the-nvss-mortality-multiple-cause-of-death-data-sets

```
map <- data.frame(widths=c(19, 1,40,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,16,4,1,1,1,1,34,1,1,4,
                           3,1,3,3,2,1,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
                           36,2,1,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,2,1,1,1,1,33,3,
                           1,1))
#Set column names 
map$cn <- c("blank", # cols 1-19
            "res_status",  #20
            "blank2", # 21-60
            "ed_v89",#61-62
            "ed_v03",#63
            "ed_flag", #64
            "death_month", #65-66
            "blank3",
            "sex", 
            "age_years",
            "age_months", 
            "age_3",
            "age_4", 
            "age_sub_flag", 
            "age_recode_52", 
            "age_recode_27",
            "age_recode_12", 
            "infant_age_recode_22", 
            "place_of_death", 
            "marital_status",
            "death_day", 
            "blank4", 
            "current_year", 
            "work_injury", 
            "death_manner", 
            "disposition",
            "autopsy", 
            "blank5", 
            "activity_code", 
            "place_injured", 
            "icd_cause_of_death", 
            "cause_recode358",
            "blank6", 
            "cause_recode113", 
            "infant_cause_recode130", 
            "cause_recode39", 
            "blank7",
            "num_entity_axis",
            "cond1","cond2","cond3","cond4","cond5","cond6","cond7","cond8","cond9","cond10",
            "cond11","cond12","cond13","cond14","cond15","cond16","cond17","cond18","cond19",
            "cond20",
            "blank7",
            "num_rec_axis_cond", 
            "blank8", 
            "acond1", "acond2", "acond3",  "acond4",  "acond5",  "acond6",  "acond7",  
            "acond8",  "acond9", "acond10", "acond11", "acond12", "acond13", "acond14", 
            "acond15", "acond16", "acond17", "acond18", "acond19", "acond20", 
            "blank9",
            "race",
            "bridged_race_flag",
            "race_imp_flag", 
            "race_recode3", 
            "race_recode5", 
            "blank10",
            "hisp",
            "blank11", 
            "hisp_recode")


#Import the file 
mort2020 <- read_fwf("./data/original/VS20MORT.DUSMCPUB_r20220105", fwf_widths(map$widths, map$cn))
```